# How to compare 2 point-clouds?

Tags: python, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, open3d

I want to compare two point-clouds using the open3d library. My main goal is to do comparison between a point cloud of an object from a LiDAR scan device and another point cloud from the 3D CAD model of the same object. But for now, I'm doing comparison between point clouds of 2 similar cars, to start with.
The point to note is, both point clouds will have different number of points.

I want to know how I should compare both point clouds to get regions of similarity or dissimilarity.

ChatGPT suggested to extract feature descriptors using FPFH method. But I don't know what to do next with them.
Please suggest how I can extract features from both point clouds and compare them. Or is there any other way to compare both the point clouds, other than feature extraction.